# multiple micro vs. one large ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Our website is getting slow and we are in need of an upgrade. 
We are currently AWS and have 1 micro ec2 instance that proved effective while our website had less traffic. Now when we get more traffic, our site is getting slower.

We can't seem to settle an argument. 
Which would be better:

1. Adding multiple additional micro/small instances and have them managed either by nginx or amazon cloud computing

OR

2. Upgrading our micro instance into a large/xlarge instance.

which would be more effective considering the tasks to be performed by the server are simple, and considering the total amount of ram and processing power is similar. 1 big, or many small?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tough to say -

Option #2 is going to be the easiest to do, turn your server off, resize it, turn it back on get more capacity just by paying more money. Easy to do, but maybe not the best long-term solution. What will you do when traffic continues to increase (either constantly or at certain times) and there are no more gains to be had simply by picking a bigger box?

Option #1 is going to be more work, but ultimately maybe a better strategy.

First of all, you didn't say if you have a constant need for more throughput, or if it is certain times of the day/week/month/year when the capacity is needed - if that is the case, multiple EC2 instances with auto-scale groups setup to respond to increases and decreases in demand by turning on additional instances as needed and then turning them off as demand decreases is a cost-effective option.

In addition, having multiple instances running - preferable in different availability zones, gives you fault-tolerance - when your big instance in #1 goes down, your website is down - if you have many small instances running across 2 or 3 availability zones, you can continue to function if one or more or your instances goes down, and even if AWS availability zone goes offline (rare, but it happens).

Besides the options above, without knowing anything about your application - other things you can do - move some static assets to S3 and/or use AWS cloudfront (or other CDN) to offload some of the work - this is often a cheap and easy way to get more out of an existing box.

Comment: This really makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't forget the network differences between the instances. The t2 instances have decreased network performance while the larger instance types have higher network performance. Regardless of which option you pick now, you should design it to easily support horizontal scaling in the future.